# Ini File opengin

Tags: vb.net

I have a applicaiton which reads from ini at startup

What i want is a vb code that will block the user from opeing the ini file manually

program could be runnung as service

eg:
C:\config.ini

program should block the user from opeing the file

Comment: First off, why? This info may help us answer the question better. Secondly, for how long? Only during the time that the ini file is read? During the time that the application is running? Or even when the application isn’t running – i.e. all the time?

Answer (score 0):

To lock a file you can use something like this. Keep in mind this is not tested. Also remember to import System.IO

```
Private Sub LockFile(ByVal file As String)

    Dim FileSt As FileStream = New FileStream("test.dat", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write)
    Try
        FileSt.Lock(0, FileSt.Length)
        Debug.WriteLine("Locked")
    Catch Ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(Ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub UnlockFile(ByVal file As String)

    Dim FileSt As FileStream = New FileStream("test.dat", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write)
    Try
        FileSt.Unlock(0, FileSt.Length)
        Debug.WriteLine("Unlocked")
    Catch Ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(Ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```